# Generate ORC file format with Snappy compression

Tags: java, snappy, orc

Assuming I have a tsv or csv file, is there any programmatic way in JAVA to convert the file to ORC file format and perform a Snappy compression on it?

Answer (score 0):

BLOT - This is a snippet and not the complete code. Please use it for reference and embed it in your solution.

Follows a quick set of instructions and you can build a MapReduce code around it.

1. Set output format and compression codec in Driver class

In your driver class, set the output format class to be ORC. Something like below [just a snippet, not the complete code]

```
Job = job = Job.getInstance(conf);
job.setOutputFormatClass(OrcOutputFormat.class);
FileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(job,SnappyCompressor.class);
```

2. The reducer needs to create the Writable value to be put into the ORC file and typically uses the OrcStruct.createValue(TypeDescription) function. For our example, let’s assume that the shuffle types are (Text, IntWritable) from the previous section and the reduce should gather the integer for each key together and write them as a list. The output schema would be struct>. As always with MapReduce, if your method stores the values, you need to copy their value before getting the next.

> ```
> public static class MyReducer
>   extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,NullWritable,OrcStruct> {
>
>   private TypeDescription schema =
>     TypeDescription.fromString("struct<key:string,ints:array<int>>");
>   // createValue creates the correct value type for the schema
>   private OrcStruct pair = (OrcStruct) OrcStruct.createValue(schema);
>   // get a handle to the list of ints
>   private OrcList<IntWritable> valueList =
>     (OrcList<IntWritable>) pair.getFieldValue(1);
>   private final NullWritable nada = NullWritable.get();
>
>   public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
>                      Context output
>                      ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
>     pair.setFieldValue(0, key);
>     valueList.clear();
>     for(IntWritable val: values) {
>       valueList.add(new IntWritable(val.get()));
>     }
>     output.write(nada, pair);
>   }
> }
> ```

This should get your data to be written in ORC format with snappy compression codec on HDFS.